# How do I get the implementation contract address from the proxy contract address?

Tags: etherscan, web3.py, abi, bsc, proxy-contracts

I'm using web3.py to interact with multiple unknown contracts, where I don't know beforehand if a contract is a proxy contract or the actual contract. I'm getting the ABIs for the contracts on-the-fly from BSCScan's API. Assume I am only interested in contracts whose ABIs are available on BSCscan.

When I retrieve the ABI of a contract from BSCScan, sometimes the ABI has functions like
`['admin', 'changeAdmin', 'implementation', 'upgradeTo', 'upgradeToAndCall']` which is how I understand it's a proxy contract address.

Now I'd like to get the address of the implementation contract from the proxy contract. The final goal is to get the ABI of the implementation contract via BSCScan, for which I need the address of the implementation contract.

How do I get the ABI (or the address) of the implementation contract?

(While I am using BSCScan and BSC, for the purposes of this answer I assume the answer for Ethereum and Etherscan is the same)

```py
from bscscan import BscScan
from web3 import Web3

contract_address = '0x88f1A5ae2A3BF98AEAF342D26B30a79438c9142e'  # Test case


def get_abi(contract_address):
    with BscScan(api_key, asynchronous=False) as client:
        abi_string = client.get_contract_abi(contract_address)
    return abi_string


web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bsc))
abi_string = get_abi(address)
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=abi_string)
if 'implementation' in [foo.function_identifier for foo in contract.all_functions()]:
    # it's a proxy contract as its ABI contained implementation()
    implementation_address = contract.functions.implementation().call()  # <-- Error
    implementation_abi_string = get_abi(implementation_address)
    contract = web3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=implementation_abi_string)


desired_result = contract.functions.somefunction().call()
```

This results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "helpers.py", line 86, in create_contract_object
    implementation_address = contract.functions.implementation().call()
  File "/venv-mac-py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 957, in call
    return call_contract_function(
  File "/venv-mac-py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1501, in call_contract_function
    return_data = web3.eth.call(
  File "/venv-mac-py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/module.py", line 57, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str, params, error_formatters)
  File "/venv-mac-py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 159, in request_blocking
    apply_error_formatters(error_formatters, response)
  File "/venv-mac-py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 63, in apply_error_formatters
    formatted_response = pipe(response, error_formatters)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 667, in cytoolz.functoolz.pipe
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 642, in cytoolz.functoolz.c_pipe
  File "/venv-mac-py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/web3/_utils/method_formatters.py", line 544, in raise_solidity_error_on_revert
    raise ContractLogicError('execution reverted')
web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted
```

Comment: Does BSCScan's [Proxy Contract Verification](https://bscscan.com/proxyContractChecker) help?

Comment: That URL works in a slightly unexpected way; it does provide an implementation address but then asks visitors to validate its output(!)
 I take it there is no standard way to link a proxy to its current implementation?

Comment: I also want to know the answer for this problem. Anyone helps?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Most proxy contracts typically have a public variable defined as a:

```js
address public implementation;
```

Which defines the address of the implementation contract. You could then call it as a view function in python, with something like:

```py
proxy_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=abi_string)
implementation_contract_address = proxy_contract.functions.implementation.call()
```

---

However, this contract, in particular, doesn't have an `implementation` function and has some private functions.

Here is the code for their proxy contract where they call the `delegatecall` to the implementation:

```js
bytes32 private constant _IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT = 0x360894a13ba1a3210667c828492db98dca3e2076cc3735a920a3ca505d382bbc;

    /**
     * @dev Returns the current implementation address.
     */
    function _implementation() internal override view returns (address impl) {
        bytes32 slot = _IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT;
        // solhint-disable-next-line no-inline-assembly
        assembly {
            impl := sload(slot)
        }
    }
```

So you'd have to read directly off the storage of the blockchain to understand what `_IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT` is. We also need to know some yul/assembly to understand what's going on.

`sload(p)` loads the value that is stored in storage at location `p`. In this contract, this means the implementation contract address is stored at location `0x360894a13ba1a3210667c828492db98dca3e2076cc3735a920a3ca505d382bbc` in memory.

We can confirm this, by looking at the `_setImplementation` method, where it stores the new implementation address with `sstore` (more Yul code, that sets a value at a location in storage).

```js
function _setImplementation(address newImplementation) private {
        require(Address.isContract(newImplementation), "UpgradeableProxy: new implementation is not a contract");

        bytes32 slot = _IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT;

        // solhint-disable-next-line no-inline-assembly
        assembly {
            sstore(slot, newImplementation)
        }
    }
```

So, all we have to do to read this, is read the address that is located in the storage of this contract at the location defined in  `_IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT`.

We can find this with:

```py
def main():
    web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("https://bsc-dataseed2.defibit.io/"))
    impl_contract = Web3.toHex(
        web3.eth.get_storage_at(
            contract_address,
            "0x360894a13ba1a3210667c828492db98dca3e2076cc3735a920a3ca505d382bbc",
        )
    )
    print(impl_contract)
```

To which we get: `0x000000000000000000000000ba5fe23f8a3a24bed3236f05f2fcf35fd0bf0b5c`

Which we then just undo the 0 padding, to get the address of:
`0xba5fe23f8a3a24bed3236f05f2fcf35fd0bf0b5c`. Which is indeed the implementation contract.

## Edit

It should be noted, that a lot of contracts will use this `IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT`, as it follows the guidelines of the [ERC1967](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1967#logic-contract-address)

Comment: That's an amazing answer with many pointers for further learning. Thanks Patrick!

Comment: Thanks so much! Do you know if we can do the same the resolve proxy contract for Ethereum mainnet and polygon?

Comment: You should be able to, but it depends on the proxy pattern the contracts use rather than the blockchain

Comment: Thanks again. for other chains, would this number be the same "0x360894a13ba1a3210667c828492db98dca3e2076cc3735a920a3ca505d382bbc" , or do we need to adjust this number for different chains?

Comment: You'd need to adjust on a per-contract basis. The implementation slot could be anything that the engineers want it to be

Comment: @PatrickCollins per-chain instead of per-contract right? I think "0x360894a13ba1a3210667c828492db98dca3e2076cc3735a920a3ca505d382bbc" could be used in any contract in BSC just not sure what will happen in polygon or ETHMainnet

Comment: No, I mean "per contract". A developer could hypothetically pick any location in storage as their `IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT`. If other contracts use that same location it's simply by convention only. `0x360894a13ba1a3210667c828492db98dca3e2076cc3735a920a3ca505d382bbc` could be used on any BSC, ETH, Polygon, etc contract. But they could use aannnyyy other location if they wanted to as well.

Comment: it should be noted, that a lot of contracts will probably use this location though, as this follows the EIP-1967 proxy standard: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1967#logic-contract-address

Comment: Seems to work on Ethereum too (I'm using it right now).

Comment: how would you get the `_IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT` dynamically though?

Comment: You'd have to find out what the storage slot of that particular variable is, which is much harder.

Comment: USDC contract has a different implementation slot. they are using keccak256("org.zeppelinos.proxy.implementation")

Answer (score 1):

When using Hardhat to deploy an upgradable contract, we could use erc1967 to get the implementation and admint contract.

```
const UpgradeableFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory(
    "Upgradeable",
    accounts[0]
  );

  const UpgradeableInstance = await upgrades.deployProxy(
    UpgradeableFactory
  );

  await UpgradeableInstance.deployed();

  const proxyAddress = UpgradeableInstance.address;
  const implementationAddress = await upgrades.erc1967.getImplementationAddress(
    proxyAddress
  );
  const adminAddress = await upgrades.erc1967.getAdminAddress(proxyAddress);

  console.log("Proxy: ", proxyAddress);
  console.log("Implementation: ", implementationAddress);
  console.log("Admin: ", adminAddress);
```

Comment: OP question refers to 3rd party proxy and implementation contracts already deployed to mainnet, not contracts deployed by themselves through hardhat.